# Dismiss popover when app goes in background

Tags: iphone, ios, uipopovercontroller

How to dismiss popover when application enters in background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the delegate method in appdelegate.m file

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //put your dissmiss popover code here
}
```

Comment: For this method to work you need to keep a reference of popoverController in appDelegate, which may not be a good choice. The answer by @David Haynes and nsgulliver would be better one.

Answer (score 5):

it is better to register your controller for `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` or `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` and dismiss it whenever your app goes to background, this will make your life quite easier i feel.

registering for notification  in your `viewDidLoad`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(myMethod)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

implement the method and

```
  -(void)myMethod{
    // dismiss popview here
    }
```

finally un-register from the notification in your view controller

```
-(void)dealloc{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: Do not want to use notifications, is there any way for getting the UIPopoverController instance from window, as we can get alerts,action sheets.

Comment: i feel it is better to use notifications instead of calling the viewcontroller's code directly in the appDelegate

Comment: I am iterating recursively over window's subviews to dismis alerts and sheets, looking for a similar kinda solution

Comment: @user1446500 you could access your window within your viewController if that's what you are asking for? `[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window;`

Comment: once you have object of main window then you could iterate to dismiss the subviews if you want like this `NSArray *subViewArray = [window subviews];
for (id obj in subViewArray)
{
    [obj removeFromSuperview];
}`

Comment: UIPopoverController is not derived from UIView, hence it will not be in subview's collection.

Comment: yes but i told about the subviews of the UIWindow as you talked about subviews, but if you are looking for popover then you should dismiss it yourself once you receive notification

Comment: Ok,does it mean, i cannot get the popover's reference in appdelegate, using window's instance?

Comment: You could declare your popOver in the delegate this is what i could think of, otherwise it is better to dismiss from the controller you are opening

Comment: did you solve your issues? you could accept the answer if it has helped you

Answer (score 4):

Send an `NSNotification` in your app delegate's `willResignActive` method, and listen for it in your view controller that contains the popup, and have it dismiss said popover when the notification is received.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   //[popover dissmissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```